# How to know if a generated image is done?

Tags: javascript, php, imagemagick

I made a script in JS to find images on my page, launch a php script to remove background with imagick and save as png on my server.

How to know in JS when my png is ready ? I do this with a load event but I think I could do something better.

For now:

```js
  const checkImage = (path,imgs) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
  /* if(...){...} */
  return resolve({path, status: 'ok'});
  }
  img.onerror = () => resolve({path, status: 'error'});
  img.src = path;
  });
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be more logical if the images on your site were already "rendered"?

Comment: It's not possible.